# How do I have a thread do different tasks consecutively for fixed time periods?

Tags: java, multithreading, benchmarking

I'm trying to get behaviour like this:

> Thread 1:  |--- 3 mins of doing task A ---|--- 3 mins of doing task B ---|--- 3 mins of task C ---|
>
> Thread 2: |--- 3 mins of doing task A ---|--- 3 mins of doing task B ---|--- 3 mins of task C ---|
>   ...
>
> Thread k: |--- 3 mins of doing task A ---|--- 3 mins of doing task B ---|--- 3 mins of task C ---|

and accumulate the results of the task B segment of each thread.

I don't need the threads to do the tasks in a synchronized way (i.e. have the start times of the task B phase aligned), but do need negligible gaps between task execution for each individual thread.

I don't have much in terms of code since I'm not sure how to structure this. So far I think I have to create `Callable` classes since I want to return a value at the end of task B, but I'm not sure if I should be creating 3 different callables for each task or if it's possible to have all of my code for the 3 tasks in 1.

The only way I can think of is do the following in each thread (in a `Callable`), but it seems like there's some extra time taken for each while loop header check, as well as the start and end time computation, and I really need precision in both the time period dedicated to the tasks, as well as to a reasonable extent their adjacency.

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
long end = start + 180*1000;
while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end)
{
    // task A
}
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
end = start + 180*1000;
while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end)
{
    // task B
}
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
end = start + 180*1000;
while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end)
{
    // task C
}
return task_b_results;
```

Is there a better way to do this? (new to Java multithreading)

Comment: Just to clarify what you want: you need that a specific thread dedicates a time slice of 3 minutes to a given task, even if this task takes less (or more) than 3 minutes? What if it takes more than 3 minutes? Will the task be resumed? What if it takes less, will the thread be idle waiting the remaining time?

Comment: is there any chance you could go into detail/give us an example of the kind of tasks A, B, and C are?

Comment: @marcospereira & clearlyspam23, Sure, so each task is essentially a series of very fast requests -- I'm calculating how many I can fit into the middle 3 minute interval (task B). Tasks A and C are identical to B but I only want to accumulate the results (number of requests executed) of task B.

Comment: @ujvl so task A, B and C will be (sort of) sending messages to each other? I mean, the results of what B is "producing" will "consumed" by A and C.

Comment: @marcospereira, No, let me clarify: tasks A, B and C occur in order. Essentially the same thing is happening in every task: I'm continuously firing requests for the entire 9 minute duration. However, in the 3 minute window of task B, I'm *measuring* the number of requests fired. Then at the end of task C, I want to return that measurement (and add it to those of other threads).

Comment: @ujvl Ok. Got it. But why you need to do that? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @marcospereira, it's tailored for benchmarking throughput specifically for a particular system, do you have any ideas on how to address the problem?

Comment: Yep. A combination of `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` and [atomic "counters"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) can help you with this scenario.

Comment: @marcospereira Could you submit an answer with a bit more detail? I'll mark it accepted once I'm able to try it out

Comment: Instead of seeing how many iterations you can perform in a fixed amount of time, why don't you see how much time it takes to perform a fixed number of iterations?  With this approach the loop overhead (for int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) is negligible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not seem to have anything to do with multithreading. Everything you describe is happening serially.
Something like this perhaps:

```
List<Task> tasks = Arrays.asList(
  new TaskA(), 
  new TaskB(), 
  new TaskC()
);
List<TaskResult> results = new List();

for(Task task: tasks) {
   long until = System.currentTimeMillis() + 180000L;
   TaskResult result = task.createResult();
   while(System.currentTimeMillis() < until) {
      result.add(task.call());
   }
   results.add(result);
}

return results.get(1);
```

Comment: Note, that you're not going to be guaranteed that the last task call is <= 3 minutes from the first.  It is possible that the thread loses CPU right after the  time check for an undefined amount of time.  On a busy system, this *could* be a lot of time.  There isn't a good solution to this problem in a non-realtime environment.

Comment: @Daniel go ahead, and suggest what you think is "a good solution" then :)
And yes, it absolutely _does_ guarantee, that the last task call is < 3 minutes from the first. You are wrong here.

Comment: I wasn't criticising your answer, only pointing out a caveat.  The caveat would be the same for any and all answers in Java.

Comment: "Not a good solution" certainly does sound like _criticism_ @Daniel :)
If _any_ solution "in java" would have the "caveat", that implies that _any_ solution in java is "not a good one". What is your language of choice then? How would you go about coming up with a "good" solution? Also, I am curious, how much time do you have in mind, when you say that a thread can lose CPU for "a lot of time"? How much is "a lot" in your opinion? Are we talking seconds? Minutes? Hours? Days?

Comment: You should read more carefully.  "Not a good solution" isn't anything that I wrote.  "There isn't a good solution to this problem" is what I wrote.  Those mean very different things.

Comment: Well, if there isn't a good solution, doesn't it mean that this particular solution isn't good?

Comment: The problem was "It is possible that the thread loses CPU right after the time check for an undefined amount of time. On a busy system, this could be a lot of time."

Comment: So, how much time exactly do you have in mind, when you say "a lot of time"?